# Get current activity from Application.Context - MonoAndroid

Tags: android, dependency-injection, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am currently developing an application using `Xamarin.Forms` that will be available on the Android and iOS platforms. When the application is first loaded on device, I check to see if there is an internet connection available on the device. I want to display a dialog box if an internet connection is not available.

Here is the following snippet of code I am using to check the internet on the `Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage`

```
if(App.Connectivity.IsNetworkConnectivityAvailable())
{
    App.Notification.DisplayLocalNotifications("No Internet", "You need an internet connection to access certain application content");
}
```

I am using dependency injection to build the appropriate module for handling dialog boxes for each appropriate environment. The Android is throwing the following exception

> Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token null is not for an application Here is the code for the
>   DisplayLocalNotification method on the Android:

```
public void DisplayLocalNotification(string title, string content)
{        
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Application.Context)
          .SetTitle(title)
          .SetMessage(content)
          .SetCancelable(true)
          .SetPositiveButton("OK", (EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>) null);

      AlertDialog alert = builder.Create();
      alert.Show();

      var okBtn = alert.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Positive);

      okBtn.Click += (sender, args) =>
      {
           alert.Dismiss();
      };
}
```

After doing some research, I need to get pass the current activity to the `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor instead of the `Application.Context`. How do I get the current activity object from the application context when you need to the activity outside of the activity context?

Comment: Does Xamarin not have the basic concept of passing an object's instance by simply using `this`?

Comment: @Squonk - Yes, it does but this code is not being called from class that inherits from the `AndroidActivity` object.  It is contained within a class that does not know the current activity object, but can access the `Application.Context` object

Comment: If you don't have an active `Activity` then you can't guarantee that one exists, Something must be active / visible in order to create the `AlertDialog` in which case you should be using that `Activity` `Context`. An `Application` in Android terms has no visibility and is basically a skeleton framework.

Comment: Hope it help http://stackoverflow.com/a/28423385/185022

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms Android platform code should assign the current Activity into Forms.Context property. This is the static Forms class and if you debug it you will see that the Forms.Context is an Activity.

```
public static class Forms
{
    public static Context Context { get; }
    public static bool IsInitialized { get; }

    public static event EventHandler<ViewInitializedEventArgs> ViewInitialized;

    public static void Init(Activity activity, Bundle bundle);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the `Xamarin.Forms.Forms` class has an Init method signature with Activity as an input parameter, but it is not accessible as a property

Comment: It is. Forms.Context is the current activity.

Comment: Thanks!  Replacing this `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Application.Context)` with this `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Forms.Context)` works

Comment: Xamarin needs better documentation on the Forms.Context object.

Comment: In general they need much better documentation.

Comment: I don't even want to know how you accessed `Forms.Context` from 
regular Xamarin.

Comment: You wouldn't access it from regular Xamarin as it's a Forms specific item. Closest would probably be Android.App.Application.Context