# How to get Image inside drawable folder as byte array or bitmap in code behind in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im trying to get an image, "stupidshit.png", that's in my drawable folder of my android projekt as byte array or bitmap in the Code behind of a ContenPage. I tried literally everything. Nothing is working for me...

Comment: Have you tried using `BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Int32)` ?

Comment: @hardartcore Where do I get "Resources" from?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780588/bitmapfactory-decoderesource-does-not-recognise-drawables

Comment: @hardartcore there is no getContext()

Comment: Do you know what is `Context`? You need a valid `Context` object in order to get a `Resources` object and pass it to `BitmapFactory`.

Comment: @hardartcore i tried Android.App.Application.Context but that doesnt have getResource... Im completely lost right now tbh... I dont know where to get a valid context object...

Comment: You need a `Context` object from an `Activity` or `Application` class if you have one declared. Where are you trying to call that? In what class?

Comment: @hardartcore I have a ContentPage and that ContentPage has a Button. When I click the Button I want to get the picture for further usage.

Comment: Here is how to get Context in Xamarin Forms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613225/get-current-activity-from-application-context-monoandroid/25614348

Comment: I dont understand that... there is not Forms.Context that i could assign the current activity into...

Answer (score 0):

> I have a ContentPage and that ContentPage has a Button. When I click
> the Button I want to get the picture for further usage.

You can use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to achieve this function.

please refer to the following code:

1.create an interface in form :

```
public interface InGetImageService
{
     Bitmap GetBitmap();
}
```

2.implement interface in android:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GetImageService))]
namespace DependencyServiceDemos.Droid
{
    public class GetImageService : InGetImageService
    {
        public Bitmap GetBitmap()
        {
            string imagefileName = "water.png";
            // Remove the file extention from the image filename
            imagefileName = imagefileName.Replace(".jpg", "").Replace(".png", "");

            // Retrieving the local Resource ID from the name
            int id = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(imagefileName).GetValue(null);

            // Converting Drawable Resource to Bitmap
            var originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(MainActivity.Instance.Resources, id);

            return originalImage;
        }
    }
}
```

3.call the following code when clicking button in `ContentPage`:

```
Bitmap bitmap =   DependencyService.Get<InGetImageService>().GetBitmap();
```

**Note:**

The `MainActivity.Instance` is a variable in `MainActivity` in android,please refer to the following code:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Instance = this;// assign a value

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```